# How to set password expiration in Weblogic 12c SQL Authentication Provider

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I have an SQL authentication provider in Weblogic 12c, my passwords in the database get automatically change frequently (daily). I have not been able to figure out why this happens or where to disable this frequent changing. 
Can someone point me to where this can be changed/disabled.

Comment: You don't even mention your database server. Do you really have hints that this is purely an issue in the application server side? Also, password expiration and password resets aren't the same thing.

Comment: I am using MySQL database server. Am not  100 % sure the cause is Weblogic but again if it is not Weblogic what else could be causing this? The passwords will be different after about 24 hours or so without my intervention.

Comment: WebLogic Server does not provide out-of-the-box this functionality in its security providers. Did you develop and deploy your own security providers that could handle password expiration ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin no, I did not develop a security provider. I used thed SQL authentication provider with an underlying MySQL database. The passwords in my database keep getting changed every single day without my intervention. What causes this to happen?

Comment: Any code inside or  outside WebLogic server could update your passwords. It could be anything from a shell script, an application, etc... disconnect your weblogic server instances from the database and see what happens.